# String Pattern Question - Core Java (repeatSeparator)

Tags: java

**Write a Java function such that Given two strings, word and a separator, return a big string made of count occurences of the word, separated by the separator string.**

```
repeatSeparator("Word", "X", 3) → "WordXWordXWord"        
repeatSeparator("This", "And", 2) → "ThisAndThis"         
repeatSeparator("This", "And", 1) → "This"
```

My code is as below but is not working

```
public String repeatSeparator(String word, String sep, int count) {        
    if(count == 1) {       
        return word;        
    }    
    if(count > 1) {       
        for (int i = 0; i < count-1; i++){        
            word = word + sep + word;           
        }       
    }               
   return word;                         
}
```

Example Output ::

```
                                   Expected         Run                  Result        
repeatSeparator("Word", "X", 3) → "WordXWordXWord" "WordXWordXWordXWord" X
```

Comment: And your question is...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The below function should do what you need:

```
public String repeatSeparator(String word, String sep, int count) {    
    StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();

    while (count > 0) {
        buffer.append(word);
        count--;
        if (count > 0) {
            buffer.append(sep);
        }
    }

    return buffer.toString();                           
}
```

Answer (score 3):

> word = word + sep + word;

Think carefully about what this does the second time around. Hint: `word` has changed since the first time around.

Solution: Use a different variable to hold the results, so that you append the same `word` each time. (Free hint: use a StringBuffer or StringBuilder instead.)

Answer (score 1):

```
public string doStuff(
    final String word,
    final String seperator,
    final int count)
{
    StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
    for (int index = 0; index < count; ++index)
    {
        if (buffer.length() > 0)
        {
            buffer.append(seperator);
        }

        buffer.append(word);
    }

    return buffer.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public String repeatSeparator(String word, String sep, int count) {        
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    sb.append(word);
    if (i < count - 1)
        sb.append(sep);
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

In real life, would use [Apache Common Lang](http://commons.apache.org/lang/) [StringUtils.repeat](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-release/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

Don't for get to consider the edge cases too. If the count is zero then the program should return an empty String.

Answer (score 0):

```
public String repeatSeparator(String word, String sep, int count) {
  String ans ="";
  for(int i=0;i<count;i++)
  {
    if(i<count-1)
    {
      ans+=word + sep;
    } else {
      ans+=word;
    }
  }
  return ans;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please try to provide an explanation for the code you posted here.

Answer (score 0):

```
public String repeatSeparator(String word, String sep, int count) {
    String s = "";

   if (count > 1)
   {
       while (count > 0)
       {
           if (count > 1)
           {
               s = s + word + sep;
               count--;
           }


           if (count == 1)
           {
               s = s + word;
               count--;
           }
        }
   }

   if (count == 1) s = word;

   return s;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static String repeatSeparator1(String word,String sep,int count){
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for(int i=0;i<count;i++){
        sb.append(word+sep);
    }
    return sb.substring(0, sb.lastIndexOf(sep));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

used this:

```
public String repeatSeparator(String word, String sep, int count) {

  String result = "";

  if(count == 0)
  return "";


  for(int i = 0 ; i < count-1 ; i++){
    result = result +(word+sep);
  }

  return result+word;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public String createSeparatorString(String word, String separator, int count) {    
    StringBuffer stringBuffer = new StringBuffer();

    while (count > 0) {
        stringBuffer.append(word);
        count--;
        if (count > 0) {
            stringBuffer.append(separator);
        }
    }

    return stringBuffer.toString();                           
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's another similar approach(I append the word at the end of every string if the count is greater than 0):

```
public String repeatSeparator(String word, String sep, int count) {
  String out="";
  if(count>0){
    for(int i=1; i<=count-1; i++){
      out += word+sep;
    }
    return out+word;
  }
  else return out;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public String repeatSeparator(String word, String sep, int count) {
   String g="";
   for(int i=0;i<count;i++){
     g=g+word;
     if(i<count-1){
       g=g+sep;
     }
  }
   return g;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        String str1="Word";
        String str2="X";
        int x=2;

        System.out.println(repeatString(str1, str2, x));

    }

    public static String repeatString(String s1, String s2, int y) {
        String dummy="";
        for(int i=1; i<=y; i++) {
            dummy+=s1;
                if(i!=y) {
                    dummy+=s2;  
                }

        }

        return dummy;

    }
```

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-‌​code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.